# $\operatorname{vec}(AB) = \operatorname{vec}(A) \otimes \operatorname{vec}(B)$

Tags: matrices, kronecker-product, vectorization

I am looking for a more elegant way to confirm the following intuition:

Assume that $A$ and $B$ are two square $p\times p$ matrices. It seems there should always be some matrix $C$ such that $\operatorname{vec}(AB) = C\left[\operatorname{vec}(A)\otimes\operatorname{vec}(B)\right]$.

Is there a more direct way to characterize $C$ (i.e. does it have some well-known name) or some general rule for creating it for a given size or create it for a given $p$?

Comment: What is $\operatorname{vec(A)}\,?$ Is it the vectorization of the matrix $A$? And what does “$\otimes$” represent in your question? The tensor product of two vectorial spaces?

Comment: Since $\operatorname{vec}(AB)=\sum_{i,j,k}a_{ik}b_{kj}\operatorname{vec}(E_{ij})=\sum_{i,j,k}a_{ik}b_{kj}\,e_j\otimes e_i$ and $\operatorname{vec}(A)\otimes\operatorname{vec}(B)=\sum_{i,k,l,j}a_{ik}b_{lj}\operatorname{vec}(E_{ik})\otimes\operatorname{vec}(E_{lj})=\sum_{i,k,l,j}a_{ik}b_{lj}\,e_k\otimes e_i\otimes e_j\otimes e_l$, $C$ is the matrix whose $\big((j,i),(k,i,j,k)\big)$-th entry is equal to $1$ for each $(i,j,k)$ and whose other elements are equal to zero.

Comment: It is the vectorization of $A$ and $\otimes$ is the kronecker product.